# How do I modify these two drop-downs VBA codes to account for deleted/edited list objects on source sheets that have been selected in drop-downs?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, spreadsheet

My Excel version is 2019, 32-bits, Professional version, Desktop.

Here is a sample Excel: https://easyupload.io/p3np6w

These are the current two VBA codes (the module code DropDownOP and the worksheet code Fundfakt-kateg-vinkl):

```
    Option Explicit
    
    Public Const DropDownsSourceRangeName As String = "Angle"
    Public Const DropDownsRangeName As String = "DropDownsRange"
    Public Const DropDownsSourceSheetName As String = "Angles for estimation"
    Public Const DropDownsSheetName As String = "Fundfakt-kateg-vinkl"
    Public Const DropDownsSourceRangeAddress As String = "$A$8:$A$1008"
    Public Const DropDownsRangeAddress As String = "$AC$4:$AI$18"
    
    'declarations for the new part:
    Public Const DropDownsSourceSheetName2 As String = "Categories for estimation"
    Public Const DropDownsSourceSheetName3 As String = "Fundamentals for estimation"
    
    Public Const DropDownsRangeName2 As String = "DropDownsRange1"
    Public Const DropDownsRangeName3 As String = "DropDownsRange2"
    
    Public Const DropDownsSourceRangeName2 As String = "Angle1"
    Public Const DropDownsSourceRangeName3 As String = "Angle2"
    
    Public Const DropDownsSourceRange2Address As String = "$A$8:$A$1008"
    Public Const DropDownsSourceRange3Address As String = "$A$8:$A$22" 'source for Fundamentals...
    
    Public Const DropDownsRange2Address As String = "$Q$4:$W$18"
    Public Const DropDownsRange3Address As String = "$A$4:$G$18"
    
    Sub AddNamedRangeAndSetDropDown()
        DeleteNamedRanges
        
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=DropDownsSourceRangeName, RefersTo:="='" & DropDownsSourceSheetName & "'!" & DropDownsSourceRangeAddress 'Angle for estimation
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=DropDownsRangeName, RefersTo:="='" & DropDownsSheetName & "'!" & DropDownsRangeAddress 'where to place the DropDown based on above source
        
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=DropDownsSourceRangeName2, RefersTo:="='" & DropDownsSourceSheetName2 & "'!" & DropDownsSourceRange2Address 'Categories for estimation
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=DropDownsRangeName2, RefersTo:="='" & DropDownsSheetName & "'!" & DropDownsRange2Address 'where to place the DropDown based on above source
        
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=DropDownsSourceRangeName3, RefersTo:="='" & DropDownsSourceSheetName3 & "'!" & DropDownsSourceRange3Address 'Fundamentals for estimation
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=DropDownsRangeName3, RefersTo:="='" & DropDownsSheetName & "'!" & DropDownsRange3Address 'where to place the DropDown based on above source
    
        SetDropDownList
    End Sub
    
    Sub DeleteNamedRanges()
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        Dim i As Long
        For i = ThisWorkbook.Names.Count To 1 Step -1
            Select Case ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name
                Case DropDownsSourceRangeName, DropDownsRangeName, DropDownsSourceRangeName2, DropDownsRangeName2, DropDownsSourceRangeName3, DropDownsRangeName3
                    ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Delete
                Case Else
                    If InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, DropDownsSourceRangeName) Or _
                        InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, DropDownsRangeName) Then _
                        If InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, DropDownsSourceRangeName2) Or _
                        InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, DropDownsRangeName2) Then _
                        If InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, DropDownsSourceRangeName3) Or _
                        InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, DropDownsRangeName3) Then _
                            ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Delete
            End Select
        Next i
        
        Exit Sub
        
    ErrorHandler:
        MsgBox "An error occurred " & Err.Description
    End Sub
    
    Sub SetDropDownList() 'No need of any iteration. Validation can be add from all the range, at once!
       Dim rngDropDown As Range, arrDrD(), arrSource(), arrAngle(), i As Long
       
       arrDrD = Array(DropDownsRangeName, DropDownsRangeName2, DropDownsRangeName3)
       arrSource = Array(DropDownsSourceRangeName, DropDownsSourceRangeName2, DropDownsSourceRangeName3)
       arrAngle = Array("Angle", "Angle1", "Angle2")
       
       For i = 0 To UBound(arrDrD)
          Set rngDropDown = Sheets(DropDownsSheetName).Range(arrDrD(i))
          
          With rngDropDown.Validation
              .Delete 'clear existd Validation rules, if any
              .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                            Operator:=xlBetween, _
                            Formula1:=getFormula1(CStr(arrSource(i)))
              .IgnoreBlank = True
              .InCellDropdown = True
              .InputTitle = vbNullString '"Select a value"
              .ErrorTitle = "Invalid value"
              .InputMessage = arrAngle(i)
              .ErrorMessage = "Select a valid value in the list."
              .ShowInput = True
              .ShowError = True
           End With
        Next i
    End Sub
    
    Function getFormula1(drDownSourceName As String) As String
        Const strStrange As String = "#$%^"
        Dim rng As Range, arr, arr1
        
        Set rng = Range(drDownSourceName) 'set the range where from to extract the list  (without blanck  cells)
        arr1 = rng.Value 'place the range in an array to finally drop its content back
        
        rng.Replace "", strStrange, xlWhole 'replace the empty cells with strStrange
        arr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng) 'place the range in a 1D array
        arr = Filter(arr, strStrange, False) 'replace the former empty cells (strStrange array elements)
        getFormula1 = Join(arr, ",")
        rng.Value = arr1 'place back the original range content
    End Function
```

The VBA code for the Fundfakt-kateg-vinkl worksheet:

```
    Option Explicit
    
    Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
      AddNamedRangeAndSetDropDown 'it recreates the validations according the the last changes in source sheets
    End Sub
    
    Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     'limit the event to trigger ONLY THE NECESSARY DROPDOWN RANGES:
     If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Me.Range(DropDownsRangeAddress), _
           Me.Range(DropDownsRange2Address), Me.Range(DropDownsRange3Address))) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    
        If Left(Target.Value, 1) = "*" And Right(Target.Value, 1) = "*" Then
            MsgBox "You can't select a heading: '" & Target.Value + "'" & vbCr & vbCr & vbTab & "Try again. ", vbCritical
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            'Target.Value = ""
             Application.Undo  'place back the value existing before change!
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
      End If
    End Sub
```

The problem: If, for instance, the value "Fund3" from the source sheet Fundamentals for estimation is selected in a drop-down on worksheet Fundfakt-kateg-vinkl and this value "Fund3" is later deleted from the source list on source sheet Fundamentals for estimation, then this deletion is not reflected in the drop-down where "Fund3" has been selected - the value "Fund3" continues to be selected in the drop-down even though it has been deleted from the source list on the source sheet.

Another issue with the current two VBA codes:

VBA DropDownOP:

```
Sub SetDropDownList()
'<…>

       

.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _

                    Operator:=xlBetween, _

                    Formula1:=getFormula1(CStr(arrSource(i)))
(Maximum 256 characters are allowed.)

`<…>
End Sub
```

Currently, the named ranges Angle and Angle1 points to cell ranges that contain 1,000 rows. This makes the workbook corrupt so it can't be re-opened. The solution might be if the data verification source could be re-pointed to the named ranges Angle, Angle1 and Angle2 in order to eliminate the issue with the limit on number of characters of 256 characters. The drawback though is that in this case, all the blank rows from the source sheet range will be displayed in the drop-downs on worksheet Fundfakt-kateg-vinkl This issue then needs a solution so that no blank rows are displayed in the drop-downs.

Problems when implementing the two VBA codes in my master Excel workbook:

1. Copy and paste three worksheets from a later version to an earlier version of the master Excel workbook
2. Add columns on the worksheet Fundfakt-kateg-vinkl in the master Excel workbook
3. Change named ranges (three named ranges for three worksheets) in the master Excel workbook
4. Change a module code and delete three worksheet codes in the master Excel workbook

In which order should I do above so that the workbook does not get corrupt by triggering VBA codes when not suitable?

This is what happens in my master Excel workbook (MEW) when trying to implement the two VBA codes:

I pasted the module code and worksheet code into my MEW but when I then go to the worksheet Fundfakt-kateg-vinkl to trig the VBA code the cursor begins to keep rotating for a long time, then this error message is displayed:

"Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error"

I click on "Debug", and the following is marked in yellow in the VBA editor in the code for DropDownOP:

```
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, _
    Formulal:=getFormula (CStr(arrSource(i)))
```

I select "Debug/Step into, and the following is marked in yellow in the code DropDownOP:

```
    Function getFormulal (drDownSourceName As String) As String
```

I select "Continue", and the same error message as before is opened in the VBA editor:

`Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error`

Overall, it takes very long time in the master Excel workbook when I switch to the worksheet Fundfakt-kateg-vinkl (4-5 seconds) - the cursor "ball" keeps spinning and I can't place or move the cursor on the worksheet during this time.

Comment: Is it a big problem to not have spaces between the categories in source sheets, which anyhow are removed when setting validation list? I mean to write all those categories (having headers between **) one after the other. When you need deleting a string, you will delete the respective row. If you want adding another one, you simple insert a row...

Comment: It seems like that is the only possibility, to not have spaces between the categories in source sheets, considering that my Excel version is 2019. So ok, let's go for that.

Comment: I can also post a piece of code to automatically delete all rows having empty cells in A:A column...

Comment: Can you translate what should I understand from "let's go for that"? I placed an answer, I sent a working workbook... Did you test the solution/workbook I provided? If tested, didn't it work as you need? I mean, **the code as it is** on the testing workbook.

Answer (score 1):

You did not answer my clarification question...

The next adapted code/solution assumes that you will not have spaces between the  categories (the ones starting and ending in *). The following code creates dynamic ranges name, able to automatically update when you delete a row, or write a new string at the end, or in an inserted row.

1. Copy the next declarations on top of a standard module (in the declarations area). Now, you will  not define the whole source range, only the starting cell:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const DropDownsSourceRangeName As String = "Angle"
Public Const DropDownsRangeName As String = "DropDownsRange"
Public Const DropDownsSourceSheetName As String = "Angles for estimation"
Public Const DropDownsSheetName As String = "Fundfakt-kateg-vinkl"
Public Const DropDownsSourceRangeAddress As String = "$A$8" ' Not "$A$8:$A$1008"
Public Const DropDownsRangeAddress As String = "$AC$4:$AI$18"

'declarations for the new part:
Public Const DropDownsSourceSheetName2 As String = "Categories for estimation"
Public Const DropDownsSourceSheetName3 As String = "Fundamentals for estimation"

Public Const DropDownsRangeName2 As String = "DropDownsRange1"
Public Const DropDownsRangeName3 As String = "DropDownsRange2"

Public Const DropDownsSourceRangeName2 As String = "Angle1"
Public Const DropDownsSourceRangeName3 As String = "Angle2"

Public Const DropDownsSourceRange2Address As String = "$A$8" ' Not "$A$8:$A$1008"
Public Const DropDownsSourceRange3Address As String = "$A$8" ' Not "$A$8:$A$22"

Public Const DropDownsRange2Address As String = "$Q$4:$W$18"
Public Const DropDownsRange3Address As String = "$A$4:$G$18"

'arrays to keep the necessary above variables in a way to allow iteration, to make the code more compact/elegant
Private arrDrD(), arrSource(), arrAngle(), arrSourceSh(), arrSourceAddr(), arrDropDAddr(), arrDrDRangeAddr()
```

2. Copy the next code inside the standard module where you placed the above declarations:

```
Sub LoadArrays() 'it loads the necessary above declared arrays, to be used in the next procedures
  Dim i As Long
   
   arrSourceSh = Array(DropDownsSourceSheetName, DropDownsSourceSheetName2, DropDownsSourceSheetName3)
   arrDrD = Array(DropDownsRangeName, DropDownsRangeName2, DropDownsRangeName3)
   arrAngle = Array(DropDownsSourceRangeName, DropDownsSourceRangeName2, DropDownsSourceRangeName3)
   arrSourceAddr = Array(DropDownsSourceRangeAddress, DropDownsSourceRange2Address, DropDownsSourceRange3Address)
   arrDrDRangeAddr = Array(DropDownsRangeAddress, DropDownsRange2Address, DropDownsRange3Address)
End Sub

Sub AddNamedRangeAndSetDropDown(Optional boolNoSource As Boolean = False)
   LoadArrays
   
   'if boolNoSource = True source names are not deleted, anymore - No need for that, they are DYNAMIC!
   DeleteNamedRanges boolNoSource
   
   Dim i As Long
   For i = 0 To UBound(arrDrD)
        If Not boolNoSource Then
            ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=arrAngle(i), RefersTo:="=Offset('" & arrSourceSh(i) & _
               "'!" & arrSourceAddr(i) & ",0,0,COUNTA('" & arrSourceSh(i) & "'!$A:$A)-1,1)"  'Name in source sheets
        End If
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=arrDrD(i), RefersTo:="='" & DropDownsSheetName & "'!" & arrDrDRangeAddr(i) 'where to place the DropDown based on above source
    
   Next i
   
   SetDropDownList
End Sub

Sub DeleteNamedRanges(Optional boolNoSource As Boolean = False)
    'if boolNoSource = True source names are not deleted, anymore
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim i As Long
    For i = ThisWorkbook.Names.Count To 1 Step -1
        Select Case ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name
            Case IIf(boolNoSource, "", DropDownsSourceRangeName), DropDownsRangeName, _
                    IIf(boolNoSource, "", DropDownsSourceRangeName2), DropDownsRangeName2, _
                    IIf(boolNoSource, "", DropDownsSourceRangeName3), DropDownsRangeName3
                ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Delete
            Case Else
                If InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, IIf(boolNoSource, "|#@$|", DropDownsSourceRangeName)) Or _
                     InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, DropDownsRangeName) Then _
                     If InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, IIf(boolNoSource, "|#@$|", DropDownsSourceRangeName2)) Or _
                     InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, DropDownsRangeName2) Then _
                     If InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, IIf(boolNoSource, "|#@$|", DropDownsSourceRangeName3)) Or _
                     InStr(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, DropDownsRangeName3) Then _
                ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Delete
        End Select
    Next i
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred " & Err.Description
End Sub

Sub SetDropDownList() 'No need of any iteration. Validation can be add from all the range, at once!
   Dim rngDropDown As Range, i As Long
   LoadArrays
   
   For i = 0 To UBound(arrDrDRangeAddr)
      Set rngDropDown = Sheets(DropDownsSheetName).Range(arrDrDRangeAddr(i))
      With rngDropDown.Validation
          .Delete 'clear existed Validation rules, if any
          .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                        Operator:=xlBetween, _
                        Formula1:="=" & arrAngle(i) 'use the named range directly
          .IgnoreBlank = True
          .InCellDropdown = True
          .InputTitle = vbNullString '"Select a value"
          .ErrorTitle = "Invalid value"
          .InputMessage = arrSourceSh(i)
          .ErrorMessage = "Select a valid value in the list."
          .ShowInput = True
          .ShowError = True
       End With
    Next i
    clearNotInListValues 'it clears selected values which are not in the source list, anymore
End Sub


Sub clearNotInListValues()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, cel As Range, list
   Dim arrIntersect, A As Range, i As Long, dict As New Scripting.dictionary
   Const strError As String = "ErrV"

   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(DropDownsSheetName)
   Set rng = Union(ws.Range(DropDownsRangeAddress), _
         ws.Range(DropDownsRange2Address), ws.Range(DropDownsRange3Address))
  
   For Each A In rng.Areas 'iterate between the range areas:

       list = Application.Transpose(Evaluate(A.Cells(1).Validation.Formula1).Value) 'extract the array from validation list
       For Each cel In A.Cells
          If cel.Value <> "" Then dict(cel.Value) = vbNullString 'collect all the unique strings from the Area
                                                                 'except the empty strings
       Next cel

       If dict.Count > 0 Then 'if at least a value has been found (except the empty string):
           'match the dict.keys with validation list to determine the common ones (the rest are Errors)
           arrIntersect = Application.IfError(Application.Match(dict.Keys, list, 0), "Err")
        
           For i = 1 To UBound(arrIntersect) 'iterate between the matching array elements
             If arrIntersect(i) = "Err" Then 'the elements not being found in the validation list:
                'Debug.Print dict.Keys(i - 1): Stop 'uncomment to visually see what will be deleted...
                A.Replace dict.Keys()(i - 1), "" 'delete the value from the respective Area range
             End If
           Next i
           dict.RemoveAll 'prepare it for the next range Area
       End If
    Next A
End Sub
```

3. Copy the next (easily) adapted code in the "Fundfakt-kateg-vinkl" code module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  AddNamedRangeAndSetDropDown True 'it recreates the validations according the the last changes in source sheets
                                   'and clear the selection where not in the validation list, anymore
End Sub

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 'limit the event to trigger ONLY THE NECESSARY DROPDOWN RANGES:
 If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Me.Range(DropDownsRangeAddress), _
       Me.Range(DropDownsRange2Address), Me.Range(DropDownsRange3Address))) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub

    If Left(Target.Value, 1) = "*" And Right(Target.Value, 1) = "*" Then
        MsgBox "You can't select a heading: '" & Target.Value + "'" & vbCr & vbCr & vbTab & "Try again. ", vbCritical
        Application.EnableEvents = False
         Application.Undo  'place back the value existing before change!
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

It calls now the main function, but without recreating the Source ranges Names, because it is not necessary, anymore. They are of dynamic type and adapts by themself (using a formula).

4. Copy the next code in `ThisWorkbook` code module. It recreates **all named ranges** and validation ranges **when the workbook is opened**.

If something not clear, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

**Edited**:

If the real workbook is huge and a lot of empty cells in A:A column of the source sheets, they can be automatically deleted very fast, using the next code:

```
Sub deleteRowsAAEmpty()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, lastR As Long, ans As VbMsgBoxResult
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 ans = MsgBox("Do you want deleting rows having empty cells in A:A column from sheet """ & ws.Name & """?" & vbCrLf & _
              "To proceed, please pess ""Yes"".", vbYesNo, "Confirm rows deletion in the NECESSARY sheet")
        If ans <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
  lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set rng = ws.Range("A8:A" & lastR)
  On Error Resume Next
   Set rng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Select 'If it select correctly, you should only replace Select with Delete
End Sub
```

As written on the last code line comment, it only selects the respective rows (to be deleted). If you like the return, it is only necessary to replace `Select` with `Delete`...

Comment: Please, download the updated testing workbook from [here](https://easyupload.io/4lg29d). It now uses ranges as validations list and is able to also clear the previous selected values which does  not exist in the new validations lists, anymore, after you delete strings from them.